# Как увеличить скорость выполнения данного кода на python?

Tags: python, оптимизация, numpy

В тестирующей системе данный код валится на времени выполнения. Каким образом можно его улучшить

```
from numpy import array


def linear_func(theta, x):
    return sum(theta*x)


def linear_func_all(theta, X):
    size = X.shape[0]
    return array([sum(theta*X[i]) for i in range(size)])


def mean_squared_error(theta, X, y):
    size = X.shape[0]
    return sum((y - linear_func_all(theta, X))**2) / size


def grad_mean_squared_error(theta, X, y):
    f = linear_func_all(theta, X)
    size = X.shape[0]
    n = [sum((f - y) * row) * 2 / size for row in X.T]
    return array(n)



X = array([[1,2], [3,4], [4,5]])
theta = array([5, 6])
x = array([1, 2])
y = array([1, 2, 1])
print(linear_func(theta, x))
print(linear_func_all(theta, X))
print(mean_squared_error(theta, X, y))
print(grad_mean_squared_error(theta, X, y))
```

Comment: Не вижу что можно ускорить. Вы и так используете numpy массивы, которые написаны на C, и по умолчанию быстрее питоновских структур данных. Переписать генераторы списков в функциях, также никоим образом не ускорит код. Он и так быстро будет работать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы используете модуль `numpy` по сути только в качестве хранилища для данных, в этой роли, он не проявляет большей части своей эффективности.

Простое правило: если у вас появилось желание работать с массивами `numpy` с помощью циклов и генераторов списков, остановитесь и подумайте, почти наверняка вы что-то делаете не так.

```py
import numpy as np


def linear_func(theta, x):
    return x @ theta


def linear_func_all(theta, X):
    return X @ theta


def mean_squared_error(theta, X, y):
    return np.mean((y - linear_func_all(theta, X))**2)


def grad_mean_squared_error(theta, X, y):
    f = linear_func_all(theta, X)
    return np.mean(2 * (f - y) * X.T, axis=1)


X = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [4,5]])
theta = np.array([5, 6])
x = np.array([1, 2])
y = np.array([1, 2, 1])
print(linear_func(theta, x))
print(linear_func_all(theta, X))
print(mean_squared_error(theta, X, y))
print(grad_mean_squared_error(theta, X, y))
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Все заработало.